# error: Expected message to be an Uint8Array - [SignTransaction - web3js]

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to generate a [signed transaction message](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-eth-accounts.html#eth-accounts-signtransaction) in a **test** method using `jest`. This test method includes a web3 call. I am using `infura provider`, `kovan` testnet and `web3js`.

The problem is this `getDepositSignedMessage()` this method returns signed transaction message on api call, but gives error on calling `npm test`.Error message is  `Expected message to be an Uint8Array`. No idea what it wants. I tried putting it with different parameters, only creates another problem. Same codes works on **browser console**, **api calls**. But not working when calling from test file.

The error occurs in `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)` this method.

[image: Error Expected message to be an Uint8Array]

Here is my test file codes.

```js
/**
 * Handles all automated tests
 */
require('dotenv').config();
const constants = require('../apis/app-constants');
const { lendingPoolV2 } = require('../repositories/abis/aave/lendingPool');
const { chains } = require('../web3/chains');

const { web3 } = chains[process.env.chain];

const getDepositSignedMessage = async (amount = 10) => {
  try {
    const asset = constants.USDC_KOVAN_ADDRESS;
    const from = constants.TEST_WALLET_ADDRESS;
    const privateKey = constants.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY;

    const lendingPoolContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      JSON.parse(lendingPoolV2),
      constants.AAVE_V2_KOVAN_LENDING_POOL
    );

    const data = lendingPoolContract.methods
      .deposit(asset, amount, from, 0)
      .encodeABI();

    const tx = {
      from,
      to: constants.AAVE_V2_KOVAN_LENDING_POOL,
      gas: web3.utils.toHex(279600),
      data,
    };

    try {
      return await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`error signing the transaction: ${error.message}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
  }
};

test('Expect signed message', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const result = await getDepositSignedMessage();
  return result;
}, 10000);
```

All I need is to create a [signed transaction message](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-eth-accounts.html#eth-accounts-signtransaction) in test file. So that I can automate the tests of my other functions. A little hint or idea would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if the value of `privateKey` is set and has expected length (String starting `0x` followed by 64 hex characters)?

Comment: @PetrHejda thanks for the comment, private key isn't started with `0x` and it has 64 characters. Just checked the length. I have exported it from metamask

Comment: Having the same issue right now, was there a solution to your problem @YeasinRahaman ?

Comment: Sorry, Haven't found any solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
const privateKey = constants.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY;
```

to

```
const privateKey = Buffer.from(constants.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY, "hex")
```